# AngularJS focusing elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following situation:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" />
<div ng-hide="!search.length || selected ">
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="poster in tasks| poster: search track by $index" ng-click="handleSelection(poster)" style="cursor:pointer" ng-class="{active:isCurrent($index)}" ng-mouseenter="setCurrent($index)">
         {{poster}}
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This all works fine and the list with the "suggested" items comes out as it should, however I would like when the user reaches certain point and presses arrow down to be able to jump to the suggested list then press enter which will populate the search box and close the suggest list.

I have tried to create a directive that binds to keydown and listen to key code, lets say 40 ( arrow down ), however even when I add tabindex to the LI elements i am not able to set focus on them. Even further I am assuming i need to know the length of the LI's so when the user reaches the last element it just stops. Same logic for going up.

thanks in advance!

EDIT: I got it, I was failing to see this entire time that there is no spoon. How about this?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-keydown="selected=false" ng-keypress="keyChanged($event);" />
<div ng-hide="!search.length || selected ">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="poster in  (filteredResults = (tasks | poster: search)) track by $index" ng-click="handleSelection(poster)" style="cursor:pointer" ng-class="  {active:isCurrent($index+1)}" ng-mouseenter="setCurrent($index+1)">
{{poster}}
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

set global

```
current = 1;
```

and in the controller like this :

```
$scope.handleSelection = function( item ) {

        $scope.search = item;

        $scope.selected = true;

    }


$scope.isCurrent = function( index ) {
       if( index === current  ) {
          return true;
       }
       else {
         return false;
       }

    }


 $scope.setCurrent = function( index ) {

         current = index;
    }


 $scope.keyChanged = function( ev ) {

      //going down
        if( ev.keyCode == 40 && (current+1) <= $scope.filteredResults.length ) {

          $scope.setCurrent( current + 1 );
        }

        //going up
        if( ev.keyCode == 38 && (current-1) >= 1 ) {
          $scope.setCurrent( current - 1 );
        }

        //press enter
        if( ev.keyCode == 13 ) {
            $scope.handleSelection( $scope.filteredResults[current-1]);
        }
    }
```

Works both with keyboard and a mouse and will stop and the first/last element. 
I have omitted the filters because they are irrelevant to the current situation.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Do you want a binding to the tab key or just up and down arrows? I have done the later but I haven't played much with the tab key.

Comment: Just up/down keys and walking over the LI's with the keys. Basically, you type something the input , the suggest list ( ul ) comes up , you press down arrow and the focus goes to the UL you can move up/down over it and press enter which closes the suggest list.

Comment: I don't really have an "answer" for you, thus the comment, but have a look at the source code for [ui-bootstrap's typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) if you want to implement something custom or just use their directive, since it sounds like it has everything you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @gentec I'll try to post some sample code from my work later today or tomorrow. It's not that hard but takes a bit of coding. I don't know about any shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: 
Use typeahead: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Solution 2, if you really need it custom:

I'd like to know if there are shortcuts but meanwhile this is how my code looks like, those are code snippets and should take them as pseudo-code and adapt it for your own project:

In a service:

```
  searchBoxData.onKeyUpAndDown = function(direction){
    searchBoxData.selected_index += direction;
    if(searchBoxData.selected_index < 0){
      searchBoxData.selected_index = searchBoxData.displayedLength() - 1;
    }else if(searchBoxData.selected_index > searchBoxData.displayedLength() - 1){
      searchBoxData.selected_index = 0;
    }
    searchBoxData.selectContent();
  };
```

In a directive

```
app.directive('fancyinput', [ "$rootScope", "SearchBoxData", function($rootScope, SearchBoxData) {

  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function link(scope, element) {


      scope.unbind_up_and_down = false;
      scope.searchBoxData = SearchBoxData;


      element.bind("keydown", function(e){
        if(e.keyCode === 13){
          scope.searchBoxData.submitQuery(e);
        }else{
          if ((e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40) && scope.unbind_up_and_down === false) {
            var direction = +1;
            if (e.keyCode === 38){ direction = -1; }
            $scope.searchBoxData.onKeyUpAndDown(direction);
          }else{
            // reset selection if typing
            scope.$apply(function () { scope.searchBoxData.selected_index = 10000; });
            scope.processBinding(e, this);
          }
        }
      });

     }

  };
}]);
```

Let me know if you need anything else. I ll update my answer accordingly.